# Only csproj file option is Active (Release)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

There's another developer  who is using the same code as I am.  I know he is because I zipped up my code repro and sent it to him.  There's a .sln file with about 10 C# project files underneath it.  One of the csproj files won't compile in debug mode.  The only option he has is Active (Release).  On my machine the properties for the same csproj file shows:

```
Active (Debug)
Debug
Release
Code Analysis Debug
All Configurations
```

He has Community Edition I have Enterprise, could this be the cause?  I know that you have to have Enterprise to use Intellitrace.  It's hard to figure out what other limitations there are for Community Edition.

He doesn't get a compilation error, he cannot pick Debug from the csproj file's properties.  It simply isn't in the list in Configuration on the Build tab.

Thanks

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: If you can't compile you should have an error in the IDE. Include that error in the question.

Comment: How can we help you without the error in question being described?

Comment: This configuration is stored in the .sln file.  It would, for example, look like `{6FD2F3DE-2F8C-4A87-84CA-BCFB6BA9CADE}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU`.  No obvious way that could go wrong, the workaround is to just put the Debug config back.  Use Build > Configuration Manager, dropdown on the Configuration column for the wonky project and select "New..."

Comment: Does the comment above can help you?